# How can we identify and authenticate platform requests (web, android, ios) on the node.js server using APIs?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, express, web

I am developing the backend on the Nodejs server using MySQL DB. I want to confirm from which device or platform as mentioned (web android or IOS) the req is coming, specifically through headers?
I really don't want to give access to miscellaneous requests to be authenticated.
Is there any module that identifies the platform/device??

P.S. I'm using the express framework.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use `npm i express-useragent` package.
It will send you below data

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var useragent = require('express-useragent');
 
app.use(useragent.express());
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send(req.useragent);
});
app.listen(3000);

// Output
{
  "isMobile":false,
  "isDesktop":true,
  "isBot":false,
  .....
  "browser":"Chrome",
  "version":"17.0.963.79",
  "os":"Windows 7",
  "platform":"Microsoft Windows",
  "source":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79..."
}
```

You can categories accordingly.
Note: If you want specific device like iOS, Android, Desktop then you should ask to send in api header data. So you will get default in all apis.